# Universal and Specific status effects

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions

I'm a new DM trying to figure out some good ways to keep track of status effects and the like (I often forget and then I'm faced with the dilemma: retcon and annoy everybody, or go with it even though it's unfair)

It seems to me that some status effects are universal -- that is, they affect a PC's relationship with everything else on the battlefield no matter what -- and other status effects are specific to certain combatants -- they only affect a PC's relationship with specific mobs.

These are the ones that are with respect to everybody

- Blinded
- Bloodied
- Dazed
- Deafened
- Dying
- Grabbed
- Helpless
- Immobilized
- Insubstantial
- Prone
- Resist
- Restrained
- Running
- Shielded (e.g. swordmage's aegis)
- Slowed
- Stunned
- Surprised
- Unconscious
- Vulnerable
- Using Total Defense

These are with respect to certain combatants:

- Charging
- Combat Advantage
- Concealment
- Cover
- Cursed (Warlock)
- Grabbing
- Hidden
- Invisible
- Long Range
- Marked
- Quarry (Ranger)
- Weakened

Is this right? Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here - what's the purpose of this list? I'm confused by blinded (a condition), resistance (a property) and Using Total Defense (a standard action) all in the same list.

Comment: I'll add "grabbing" to the _biased_ ones.

Comment: The purpose is that when I'm keeping track of conditions, properties, and status effects of PCs, NPCs, and mobs, which ones can I just tick off a box for/use a status marker token, and which ones do I have to record extra information such as "...related to such-and-such mob".

Comment: You missed ongoing damage.  There are also auras which aren't technically status effects, but are easy to forget.

Comment: You also left out flying or hovering for everybody effects. Also, under 'marked' there should be cursed, and quarry if you want to get that detailed.

Comment: Can you imagine if any monster/player had most of these conditions at once?

Comment: @snowbody While seeing the list of all potential status effects is quite fascinating (and terrifying as a player!) I'm not quite certain I see the merit to this, much less a real question.

Comment: I would agree that this probably needs to be crafted into a little more of a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way this is managed is a chit or counter attached to the mini(s).

If you are using a white/chalkboard or paper, just writing an abbreviation next to the individual in question may work as well.

Comment: Yes, but I've noticed that for some effects, a chit or counter attached to the mini is not sufficient, because it doesn't specify which other entities the effect is relative to.

Comment: The trick here is colors.  You will have a max of 6 PCs so you can just use 6 colors.  If a mob is hidden from the green player. Put a  green obscured marker on the mob, etc.

Comment: @GMnoob, that's brilliant!